# i am trying to update my data with an image updation too but the image isset would not work in php

Tags: php, mysql, image

Hey guys i have created a register form with an image upload too but when i try to update this form  i try to get the id but the isset of my image is not working so it just wont run my update query do check it out

this is the updation form where all the values will be displayed for edit now can i run the update function in the isset condition of my submit button and then update the data

```
    <title>Register Update</title>
<?php
//error_reporting(0);
$id=$_GET['id'];

function __autoload($classname)
{
include "$classname.php"; 
}
$obj = new connect();
$st=$obj->con();

if (isset($_POST['sub'])) 
{
$upd= new update();
$upd->updatedata($_POST);
}





$qry = "select * from register ";
$run = mysqli_query($st,$qry);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run);
 {
 $g = $row['gen'];
 $l = $row['lang'];
}


$query=mysqli_query($st,"select * from register where id='$id'");
//echo "<ul>";
while($query2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    //print_r($query2);
echo "<form method='POST' action='RegisterRetrieve.php'>";
echo "<table>";
?>

<p><input type="hidden" name="sid" value="<?php echo $query2['id']; ?>"></p>
<tr>
<td>
First Name:
</td>
 <td><input type="text" name="uname" value="<?php echo $query2['uname']; ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password:</td>
    <td><input type="password" name="pwd" value="<?php echo $query2['pwd']; ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Email Id:</td>    
<td><input type="text" name="emailid" value="<?php echo $query2['emailid']; ?>"
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Radio Button: Are you male or female?</td>
    <?php
    if ($g == "male"){
echo "<td><input type='radio' name='gen' value='Male' id='gen' checked> Male <input type='radio' name='gen' value='Female' id='gen'> Female </td>";
 }
 else
 {
 echo "<td><input type='radio' name='gen' value='Male' id='gen'> Male <input type='radio' name='gen' value='Female' id='gen' checked> Female </td>";
 }
    ?>
</tr>
<tr>    
<td>Check Box: Check the languages you know?</td>
<td><?php
    $lang=explode(',',$l); 
    //print_r($lang);
        if(in_array('Cricket', $lang))
            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="lang[0]" value="Cricket" checked>Cricket';
        else
            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="lang[0]" value="Cricket">Cricket';
        if(in_array('Basketball', $lang))
            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="lang[1]" value="Basketball" checked>Basketball';
        else
            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="lang[1]" value="Basketball">Basketball';

        if(in_array('Hockey', $lang))
            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="lang[2]" value="Hockey" checked>Hockey';
        else
            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="lang[2]" value="Hockey">Hockey'."<br>";  
    ?>   
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Mobile No:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="mobile" value="<?php echo $query2['mobile']; ?>"
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>10th Marks:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="marks_10" value="<?php echo $query2['10marks'];?>"
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
12th Marks:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="marks_12" value="<?php echo $query2['12marks'];?>"</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Browse Image:</td>
<td><input type="file" name="file1"></td>
<td><img src='img/<?php echo $query2['name'];?>' width='150px' height='150px'></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<select name="priority">
<option value="admin">
admin
</option>
<option value="<?php echo $query2['priority']; ?>"><?php echo $query2['priority']; ?>
</option>
<option value="superadmin">
superadmin
</option>

</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="sub"><br>
</td>
</tr>
<?php

echo "<table>";
echo "</form>";
}
//echo "</ul>";



?>
```

now my update query which i m using but when i try to isset my image it just wont go in that condition

```
    <?php

class update extends connect
{

    function updatedata($rel)
    {
        $obj= new connect();    
        $obj->con();


        extract($_POST);

        $id=$_GET['id'];

        $line = implode("," ,$lang);
        print_r($_POST);   


        if(isset($_FILES["file1"]))
        {

        extract($_POST);
        echo "hello";
        $name = $_FILES['file1']['name'];

        $type = $_FILES['file1']['type'];

        $size = $_FILES['file1']['size'];

        $tmp_name = $_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'];

        $loc = 'img/';

        $ext = substr($name,strpos($name,'.')+1);

        if($_FILES['file1']['size']>= '10000' || $_FILES['file1']['size']<="23000000")
        {
            //echo $size;
        }
            else{
            //  echo "size is not supported";
            }
        $val = $_FILES['file1']['size'];

         if($ext == 'jpg' || $ext == 'png')
            {
    //echo $lang;
    //print_r($_POST);
    //exit;
    $val =("update register set uname='$uname',pwd='$pwd',emailid='$emailid',gen='$gen',lang='$line',mobile='$mobile',10marks='$marks_10',12marks='$marks_12' file1='$name' where id=$sid");
    //print_r($qry);

    $res=mysqli_query($this->con(),$val);
    //print_r($run);
    if($res)
    {
            move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$loc.$name);
            //echo "data saved";
        //echo "Data inserted";

        }
        else
        {
            //echo "Data Not Inserted";

            }

    }
}
}


        //print_r($val);

    //  return $res;
    }
?>
```

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Answer (score 0):

Your html is broken:

```
</tr>
<?php

echo "<table>";    <--shouldn't this be </table>?
echo "</form>";
}
```

Comment: it seems that when i run the update query my isset($_FILES['file1']) does not run do you got an idea about that?

Comment: so start doing basic debugging: `var_dump($_POST, $_FILES)` and see what's showing up.

Comment: its showing something like this can you check it out ?  C:\wamp64\www\projectexam\update.php:19:
array (size=0)
  empty

Comment: you forgot the `enctype` on your `<form>` tag

Comment: thank you that did got me through but now the image file is still not showing here is an image link   http://imgur.com/a/gQoqt

Comment: Look, we're happy to help, but this isn't a debugging service. You need to start tracking things down yourself.